# Different measurability of Hilbert-space valued random variable

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

My question is motivated by [this link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/88868/choice-of-predictable-or-jointly-measurable-eigenvalues-and-eigenvectors-of-nu).

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ and $(Y,\mathcal{B})$ be measurable spaces, a measurable map $T:\Omega\to Y$ is called  a $Y$-valued random variable.

Now let $H$ be a separable real Hilbert space, $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space, and $Q:\Omega\to \mathcal{L}(X)$ be a measurable  map taking values in the space of  positive semidefinite, self-adjoint, trace class operator.
One aim is to select measurable  $\gamma_n:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ (eigenvalues) and  $x_n:\Omega\to H$ (eigenvectors) such that
$Q=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \gamma_n x_n\otimes x_n$.

By following the book  by Zabczyk and Peszat, entitled "Stochastic Partial Differential Equations driven by Levy Noise" page 115, they apply the Kuratwoski-Ryll-Nardzesk section theorem, and select eigenvectors from the set
$K:=\{x\in H: |x|_H\le 1\}$ endowed with the weak topology (so compact by Alagou).

**My question is:**  does this procedure only prove the measurability of $x_n:\Omega\to H$, where $H$ is endowed with the **weak topology**? Is it equivalent to the original definition of being a random variable, whose topology is generated by the norm of $H$?

Comment: Check out the Pettis measurability theorem.

Comment: @terceira Could you elaborate it more by writing it as an answer?